# alternative to tail -f | grep server logs

Tags: testing, logging, functional-testing, tail

Currently, I'm making curl calls, check the response and some times do a "ssh HOSTNAME "tail -f LOGFILE" | grep PATTERN.  Is there a tool out there that streamline/generalize this process of making some request, checking both the response and server logs for certain patterns?  (Oh, and getting statistics like response time would be plus)

Answer (score 0):

I've only got an answer to part of your question.  To get good stats out of cURL, try something like this:

```
curl -w '\nLookup time:\t%{time_namelookup}\nConnect time:\t%{time_connect}\nPreXfer time:\t%{time_pretransfer}\nStartXfer time:\t%{time_starttransfer}\n\nTotal time:\t%{time_total}\n' -o /dev/null -s http://www.google.com/
```